# why does it always use headers in php with email sending

Tags: php, http-headers

My question is why people use headers with email sending in php. I know we can send some information to browser before it renders content. But when we show images on email body , I notice that it uses php headers. Can't we do it without headers? Because that is rendring html on a web browser.

Comment: The email headers are what cause the email to be delivered.

Comment: Does it mean that we can not send email without headers?

Comment: Can you show some example code of what you're asking about. What kind of headers?

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell browser what type of content are we rendering .. e.g is it plain text , html page , pdf file etc ...
So when ever we want to have html in our email body we need to tell browser about it so that it can be properly handled

Answer (score 1):

No. Sending an Email must contain a `from` header. It is well written in [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

```
When sending mail, the mail must contain a From header. This can be set with the additional_headers parameter, or a default can be set in php.ini.

Failing to do this will result in an error message similar to Warning: mail(): "sendmail_from" not set in php.ini or custom "From:" header missing. The From header sets also Return-Path under Windows.
```

You can set it in `php.ini` if you dont want to use additional headers.

Comment: The php `mail` function will use the server's admin email as the `From` header if one isn't given.